# Was the downing of a Russian IL-76 over Russia by Ukraine a crime, and if so what are the consequences?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine

On January 24, Russian military transport aircraft IL-76 was shot down on Russian territory. Russia claims that it had carried out the ukrainians war prisoners for the exchanging on russian ones, and that 64 ukrainians POWs and 9 russians aircraft personals were killed.

[The russian experts investigation have claimed that aircraft was shot down by Patriot(a surface-to-air missile system).](https://tass.com/politics/1740329)

Ukraine disputes that the plane was carrying POWs, or that there was a claim that it was carrying POWs prior to it being shot down.

Putin directly said:

["Russia insists on international probe into Il-76 plane crash."](https://tass.com/politics/1739957)

Ukraine has pointed out several members of the POW list had previously been exchanged and are currently free and in Ukraine.

For more details, https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-ukraine-had-15-minute-warning-pow-flight-kyiv-demands-international-2024-01-25/

Was the downing of this plane a crime? If so, what are the consequences for those who provide air defense weaponry?

Answer (score 6):

AFAICT, [it's](https://www.voanews.com/a/un-security-council-discusses-russian-military-plane-crash-near-ukraine-border-/7457995.html) mostly Russia trying to make a big deal out of it, like even calling a UN Security Council meeting over it. And Ukraine accusing Russia in return of not allowing an international investigation. Most Western countries seem to have said little or nothing about it. And the US foreign policy agenda is [busy](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-68171280) with strikes against Iran's proxies right now, so there's not much chance anything going on in Russia-Ukraine will capture [their] attention.

As for the EU, [news](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-68165971) is that they've approved a 50 billion euros package for Ukraine, after managing  to placate Orban, again (apparently by including language on Ukraine respecting the rights of minorities, but there may have been other qui-pro-quo inducements not publicized.) Anyhow, the Il-76 shootdown does not appear to have affected the EU agenda in any way.

It's been mentioned by the OP in the comments that the event might be relevant because NATO countries have promised that their weapons [given to Ukraine] will not hit [pre-war] Russian soil. It's not clear to me though the extent to which that promise ever applied to anti-aircraft missiles, [because](https://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/ukraine-russia-refused-turn-bodies-plane-crash-victims-106890378):

> Ukraine previously claimed credit for a May 2023 cross-border strike with Patriot missiles.
>
> Ukrainian air force spokesman Yuriy Ihnat said in an interview in November the Ukrainian military used Patriots to down two Russian warplanes and three helicopters over Russia’s Bryansk region in May in what he called a “brilliant” operation.

So, anyhow, that ship had sailed almost a year ago.

As for the Russian claim that they informed Ukraine beforehand about the flight [having POWs on board], Ukraine seems to dispute that:

> Ukrainian officials emphasized that Moscow didn’t ask for any specific stretch of airspace to be kept safe for a certain length of time, as it has for past POW exchanges.

According to Ukraine, a Russian A-50 AWACS, based on the Il-76 body, was also shot down recently [in mid-January, over the sea of Azov], but there are [conflicting reports](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-ukraine-war-a-50-radar-plane-shot-down-claim/32776768.html) as to the weapon that might have struck that. AFAICT, Russia [has not](https://www.dw.com/en/how-kyiv-shooting-down-a-russian-spy-plane-could-impact-war/a-68013795) officially commented on that loss claim. A West Point blog (from an air defense specialist/instructor nonetheless) even [claims](https://mwi.westpoint.edu/awacs-over-the-azov-takeaways-from-ukrainian-air-defenses-latest-score/) that simultaneously there was a "companion AWACS orbiting over Belgorod". I'm not sure how seriously we can take that latter claim. On a quick search I could find no other claims like that, even from Ukraine. Anyhow, I guess it's possible that some Western/Ukrainian intel might have thought that was the case, at one point at least.

Comment: And Ukraine accusing Russia in return of not allowing an international investigation.  - sorry, dude, it is not actual. Putin ask to investigate... i understand that you have to flood down the theme, but it is a serious cause close to open conflict between Rus and the US.

Comment: @άνθρωπος It is easy to say you want an international investigation in a press release but not actually allow one to happen. Until we see some movement on it all we have is what both sides are claiming.

Comment: It's not a question of media attention which is less relevant than it tries to self-prophet.

Comment: Other articles [confirm](https://apnews.com/article/ukraine-russia-surveillance-defense-war-65b93d45f67204c9db7a07330e7220970) that Russia was regularly flying their AWACS over the Azov sea, where they mutually detected [and were detected by] NATO AWACS flying way over Romania. But I can't find other pieces saying if Russia flew their AWACS in the Belgorod region with any regularity.

Comment: I managed to find a [US statement on this](https://osce.usmission.gov/right-of-reply-to-the-russian-federation-on-the-il-76-plane-crash/). They cast doubt on Russia's version of events and said that in any case the responsibility for the deaths rests with Russia.